# Star trails image stacking in python

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to make some strar trail pictures in python, and I seem to be missing some basic understanding of how the image library works. Because in my head, it should work fine to just add all the frames together and divide it by the number of frames.

However that gives a completely black picture, while just adding them gives the picture below.

Code:

```
import Image
import numpy as num

data = num.genfromtxt('list.txt',dtype='str')

pic = 0

for i in range(len(data)):
    im1=Image.open(data[i])
    pic1=num.array(im1)
    pic = pic + pic1 
    print(i)

pic = pic/2

im = Image.fromarray(pic)
im.save("pytrail.jpg")
print(i/len(data))
```

Result:
[image]

Now if I grab some code from the net:

```
from PIL import ImageChops
import os, Image

data = num.genfromtxt('list.txt',dtype='str')
finalimage=Image.open(data[0])
for i in range(1,len(data)):
    currentimage=Image.open(data[i])
    finalimage=ImageChops.lighter(finalimage, currentimage)
finalimage.save("allblended.jpg","JPEG")
```

I get this:
[image]

But I'm not sure how this is different.

> lighter
>
> ImageChops.lighter(image1, image2) ⇒ image
>
> Compares the two images, pixel by pixel, and returns a new image
>   containing the lighter values.
>
> ```
> out = max(image1, image2)
> ```

I get that this seeks out the lighter pixels, but that should be a form of averaging right?
Is there a way to make my way work? (even if it means reduced brightness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really averaging. Let's see a quick example:

```
# Averaging
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> b = np.array([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
>>> (a + b) / 2
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

And now let's take the "lighter" values for each position:

```
>>> np.max([a, b], axis=0)
array([6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6])
```

This second method should work for you. Just "stack" the images and ask Numpy to return a new frame with the maximum values of each one. In an ideal world your background would be exactly the same and then `np.max` would return different values only in the pixels where you've registered stars, giving you the trails.

Comment: Ok that seems to work! but why can't I get a normal pic that first way? It would be great to average somehow, as that would remove the clouds :P

Comment: Maybe you could substract the averaged image from the one with the maximum values? I'm not too versed in image processing O:-). I work with astronomers, though. Let me ask..

Comment: (On second thought: no, that won't help much). The answer I got was: "why to remove the clouds? They're nice!" Hint: don't ask the astronomer with an eye for photograph...

Comment: Maybe you could try with some [background substraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_subtraction) techniques? That way you could get just the stars and apply them on top of one of the frames. More involved, but...

Comment: I just tried it and it looks even more like modern art now xD
http://i.imgur.com/ughZnOm.jpg

Comment: (I wonder what those fringe patterns are though) and background substraction looks interesting. Let me read up on that. (not sure if I'll be wanting to put in the time though :P)

Comment: Anyway, the cloud removal is a separate problem, uh? ;) The star trails is solved :D